# jQuery Mobile - Set select options as months

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a select field in JQM 1.4.5 that looks like this:

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <select class="myMonthSel" name="select-native-2" id="select-native-2 monthSel" data-mini="true">
         <OPTION value="NONE">Select a date</OPTION>
    </select>
</div>
```

I am trying to dynamically load the options with months starting with the most current month. The function i am currently using looks like this:

```
function populateMonths() {

var months = {
    "0": "January",
    "1": "February",
    "2": "March",
    "3": "April",
    "4": "May",
    "5": "June",
    "6": "July",
    "7": "August",
    "8": "September",
    "9": "October",
    "10": "November",
    "11": "December"
};

var monthSel = $('.myMonthSel');

console.log(monthSel.length);
var curDate = new Date;

for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    var val = (curDate.getMonth() + i) % 12;
    console.log(months[val]);
    monthSel.options[monthSel.length] = new Option(months[val], i);
}
} populateMonths();
```

I'm receiving the error in console:

> TypeError: Cannot set property '2' of undefined

I've tried a few different options including, changing the selector to 
$('.myMonthSel > option) and using an array instead of an object for months.

Not sure what i'm doing incorrectly for this to not show up. I have a working jfiddle with the function here: https://jsfiddle.net/75exLm8a/11/

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```js
function populateMonths() {
  var months = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
  ],
  curMonth = new Date().getMonth(),
  html = '<option data-placeholder="true">Select a date</option>';
  for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    var val = (curMonth + i) % 12;
    var monthName = months[val];
    var isoMonth = ("0"+(months.indexOf(monthName)+1)).substr(-2);
    html += '<option value="'+isoMonth+'">'+monthName+'</option>';
  }
  $('#select-month').html(html).selectmenu("refresh");
}

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page-one", function() {
  populateMonths();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="page-one" data-role="page">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <select id="select-month" name="select-month" class="myMonthSel" data-native-menu="false" data-mini="true">
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! This led me in the absolute perfect direction. How difficult would it be to modify the option value toISOString ?